# Junit5 verify if an exception was thrown during the execution

Tags: java, junit, junit5

In JUnit5 how can I verify if an exception was ever thrown but later caught during execution?
For instance, consider

```
public Optional<Foo> MethodA(Argument a)  {
try {
    /*
        Some logic based on Aargument a providing biproduct Argument b
    */

        methodB(b)

    /*
        some other logic capable of throwing exception
    */

    } catch(Exception e) {
        // log  exception
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}

private BReturnValue MethodB(Argument b) throws Exception{
    throw new IllegalStateException() 
}
```

Now no matter which method, whether A or B throws exception, as a return value of MethodA, I will receive an empty Optional and hence i cant use assertThrows() but I am actually testing a test case which will cause MethodB to throw exception.
Can I, and if yes, How can I verify if  during the during the execution an exception was thrown from `MethodB`?

**Note**

- Currently I am using 2 tests, one to verify if empty Optional is being returned and another one to directly call MethodB() by manually providing `biproduct argument` and using `assertThrows()`.

But I am looking for some better way to verify that the `biproduct argument` was formed by MethodA and methodB threw exception. And I don't want to test `MethodB` directly, but through `MethodA`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JUnit has no way of detecting a thrown-and-caught exceptions. It would require analyzing the execution, and while it would probably be technically feasible in some way, it would be counterproductive to implement such a complex mechanism.

In this case I'm wondering why does it matter to the test where the exception is thrown? In any case the test fails provided your test considers `Optional.empty()` return value as a failed test, although maybe it shouldn't be catching the exception at all. In this case if the test fails you have to do extra work to determine what went wrong, but you still got the important information: something went wrong.

If you feel it's important to know where the exception is happening, then the methods should most likely be tested separately, which requires redesigning/refactoring the code to be more easily testable.